# Fedora 28 - ssh - Could not resolve hostname

Tags: ssh, fedora, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to access my raspberrypi through ssh for the first time in my Fedora 28.

I ran `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` but i got this error.

[image: error when using fedora]

I tried to run exactly the same command in another OS and it works as I expect:

Linux Mint 18.3:
[image: working in lmint]

Ubuntu 16.04:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that is working is running avahi/zeroconf, the system where ssh is working is not.

Avahi propagates the relation between hostnames and IP addresses between machines, between other information.

Get the IP address of the rapsberry from the system that is working, and ssh the IP address instead of the name.

Alternatively, to install avahi, do:

```
sudo yum install avahi avahi-tools
```

Comment: Using the ip instead of `raspberry.local` it works, but how can I set my computer to recognize and connect using `raspberry.local`?

Comment: @MateusKoppe Added to the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux!

Comment: I think you should also make sure `nss-mdns` is installed, it wasn't pulled in by default when I tried it. Also you will either need to reboot, or run `systemctl start avahi-daemon`, before Avahi gets started. Fedora is just that fun :). And just to be sure, you should check it shows as "enabled" in `systemctl status`, otherwise run `systemctl enable avahi-daemon`. This is not necessary on a Fedora Workstation install, but it might be necessary in other spins. (Workstation allows avahi-daemon to be enabled by default, in the Workstation systemd preset file). Normally avahi is already installed